# How many Pokemon Eggs does an Incubator hatch?

Tags: pokemon-go

After a certain amount of uses, an Incubator becomes unusable. Is this a set number of eggs or is it a range?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The incubator has a number under it with its uses.

The one you get at the start has unlimited uses. The one you get at level six has only 3 uses before it breaks.

Comment: Incubators purchased from the shop have only 3 uses as well. The first one's always free...

Comment: In order to maximize the use you get out of the 3 time use incubators, hatch the 10km eggs in those while hatching 2km eggs in the infinite incubator. (I split 5km eggs between them depending on how many I have.) This way you can get the most distance and use out of the 3 time use incubators.